# Get siblings from header until next header in an unsemantic table

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) I'd like to parse a webpage containing a very unsemantic table. What I'm looking for is a "print every following-sibling until you meet the following element"-XPath-query.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#CCDDEF;">
        <td colspan="4"> <b>HEADER1</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title1.1</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>Info1.1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#CCDDEF;">
        <td colspan="4"> <b>HEADER2</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title2.1</td>
        <td>Name2.1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title2.2</td>
        <td>Name2.2</td>
        <td>Info2.2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#CCDDEF;">
        <td colspan="4"> <b>HEADER3</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title3.1</td>
        <td>Name3.1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to group every Title, Name, Comment and Note under each header. I have tried with various XPaths (with variations of `following-sibling`, `preceding-sibling` and `count`) but I either get nothing, everything or every `tr` which is not a header.

I'm currently getting the headers with `//tr[@style]` or `//tr[td[@colspan="4"]]`.

The following is the parse-function in my Scrapy-spider (which prints the header and all of the `tr`'s which is not a header):

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//*[@id="content-text"]//tr[td[@colspan="4"]]')
    for site in sites:
        print site.select('./td/b/text()').extract()
        print site.select('./following-sibling::tr[not(td[@colspan])]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XPath expression**:

```
/*/tr[@style or td[@colspan='4']][1]/following-sibling::tr
       [count(. | /*/tr[@style or td[@colspan='4']][2]/preceding-sibling::tr)
       =
        count(/*/tr[@style or td[@colspan='4']][2]/preceding-sibling::tr)
       ]
```

**selects all `tr` elements that are between the 1st and 2nd headers**:

```
<tr>
   <td>Title1.1</td>
   <td>-</td>
   <td>Info1.1</td>
   <td/>
</tr>
```

To select all `tr` elements that are between the Kth and (K+1)th headers, simply replace in the above expression `1` with `K` (the number) and `2` with `K+1` (the number).

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/tr[@style or td[@colspan='4']][1]/following-sibling::tr
             [count(. | /*/tr[@style or td[@colspan='4']][2]/preceding-sibling::tr)
             =
              count(/*/tr[@style or td[@colspan='4']][2]/preceding-sibling::tr)
             ]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#CCDDEF;">
        <td colspan="4">
            <b>HEADER1</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title1.1</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>Info1.1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#CCDDEF;">
        <td colspan="4">
            <b>HEADER2</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title2.1</td>
        <td>Name2.1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title2.2</td>
        <td>Name2.2</td>
        <td>Info2.2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#CCDDEF;">
        <td colspan="4">
            <b>HEADER3</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title3.1</td>
        <td>Name3.1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes are copied to the output:**

```
<tr>
   <td>Title1.1</td>
   <td>-</td>
   <td>Info1.1</td>
   <td/>
</tr>
```

**Explanation**:

This is a simple application of the Kayessian (after Dr. Michael Kay) formula for node-set intersection:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

In this particulat case we substitute `$ns1` with:

```
/*/tr[@style or td[@colspan='4']][1]/following-sibling::tr
```

and we substitute `$ns2` with:

```
/*/tr[@style or td[@colspan='4']][2]/preceding-sibling::tr
```

Comment: I guess I better read up on the Kayessian formula. What exactly does `.` refer to? Current selection…? This XPath-query works with everything between headers. How would I extend it to further include everything from the last header and down?

Comment: @Josso, "." means the context node. As for finding the `tr` s after  the last header, this is much simpler: `/*/tr[@style or td[@colspan='4']][last()]/following-sibling::tr`

Comment: I was thinking of combining the XPath-queries, but I might as well just go with this. I will try to read up on XPath. It looks very fascinating and very mystique. Not widely used but enough so that it is useful to learn.

Comment: @Josso, You are welcome. For good books on XPath/XSLT, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/36305